# How to call blazor onclick method with static render mode

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, razor, blazor

How to call onclick method while rendering component as a static html? I mean, is there any workarounds in JavaScript?

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Awesome>(RenderMode.Static))
```

And the Awesome.razor

```
<h3>@name</h3>

<button @onclick="@(() => name = name.ToUpper())">Upper case me</button>

@code {
    string name = "Mr. Blazor";
}
```

While using ServerPrerendered it seems to work because oninitialize method is fire, but again onclick doesn't work.

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Awesome>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
```

Comment: [Polite] I'm not sure in the point of this question.  You render something static then expect it to be not static?  Workaround in JavaScript: what you you want to happen?  If it's the `name` field to update then don't render static.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis in some browser blazor component just not render, even with polyfill, so the solution for me is to find some workaround for statics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.rendermode?view=aspnetcore-6.0#fields) say:

> Static :  Renders the component into static HTML

That means an `@onclick` will never work, nor anything else in written in C#.

> is there any workarounds in JavaScript?

JavaScript will still work, use `onclick` (without the `@`).  But that won't let you use this `name` variable.